# how to get the url of a custom uploaded file

Tags: plugins, uploads

For a custom function I need to generate a file, upload it to the upload folder and also access the upload file afterwards to attach the file to an email.

For uploading the file I use the wp_upload_bits function. But how do I get the upload url so I can attach the file to an email afterwards?

Or should I use the wp_handle_sideload function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_upload_bits` will return an array with info about the URL, as mentioned [in the documentation for it](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_bits/#return).

So it would look something like this:

```
$results = wp_upload_bits( ... );
$url = $results['url'];
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed it that you can just grab the url like that. Works great!